# How to remove pause video suggestions / related videos (class: ytp-pause-overlay) from Youtube embed

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, youtube

I have embedded youtube videos on my site. When I pause the video, it show a list of more videos and when video ends it displays a list of suggested videos. I do not want to show these suggested videos on my site.

On inspecting the video, I get the following code

```
<iframe title="Dummy Video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dummyvideo?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="" name="dummyvideo"></iframe>
```

I tried to disable the suggested videos from css, but it's not completely working, for the first time it shows the more video links but later on it hides and when video ends, it always shows the suggested videos.

Here is my css that I have tried

```
.ytp-pause-overlay {
    display: none !important;
}

.ytp-endscreen-content {
    display: none !important;
}
```

I also tried this JS code, but it's not working

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-pause-overlay ytp-scroll-min")[0].style.display = 'none';
```

But it's not working and also giving an error on console. Also it should be fired on when someone pause the video otherwise it will throw an error.

Is there any way through which I can target for all the videos using CSS and JS

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible anymore to apply custom CSS on the content of an iframe.
So in other words: i'm afraid this won't be possible with JS or CSS.